# Linear Algebra: if $A$ spans $B$, does $B$ necessarily span $A$ if $\dim A = \dim B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Thanks for looking at my question!

Given:

I:  $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ linear independent vectors and $\{c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$ linear independent vectors.

II:  $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ span the same subspace as $\{c_1,\ldots, c_n\}$

Does $\{c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$ necessarily span the subspace spanned by $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$?
Note that dimension of $B ={}$dimension of $C = n$.

I'm pretty sure it does, but am not sure how to prove it.
Also, is there any better way to write this? It's certainly less than poetic.

Comment: If $n = \aleph_0$, this fails. Consider $k\mathbb{Z}$ - a vector space over the field $k$ spanned by integer numbers. Its subspace $k(2\mathbb{Z})$ has the same dimension, yet it's a proper subspace.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko In mathematics, $n$ tends to stand for natural numbers. But you might like the sequence $(n_\epsilon)$ that goes to zero as $\epsilon$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @Alexei: Not only does $n$ usually stand for natural numbers, the notation $\{b_1,\dotsc,b_n\}$ almost always stands for a finite set, and if you wanted it to stand for something else then $n$ would have to be an appropriate ordinal.

Comment: The question seems to be tautologiacally true. If I read point II, it says the subspace spanned by $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ (call it $V_1$) equals the subspace spanned by $\{c_1,\ldots,c_n\}$ (call it $V_2$). And you are asking whether $V_2=V_1$? Well if $V_1=V_2$, then obviously "yes". Am I missing something?

Comment: To add to my previous comment, with the above definitions you statement II could conceivably be interpreted as affirming any one of the statements $V_1\subseteq V_2$ (the $b_i$ span a subspace of the subspace $V_2$ spanned by the $c_i$), $V_1\supseteq V_2$ (the $b_i$ span at least $V_2$), or $V_1=V2$ (the $b_i$ span exactly the subspace $V_2$ spanned by the $c_i$). I think the last reading is what it says, but maybe not what was intended (given the number of answers people have read your mind better than I can; I feel stupid). Please clarify.

Comment: Cross-posted to stats.SE and migrated back here as a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257027. Please do not cross-post without indicating that you did; this migrated duplicate is but one example of the inefficiencies this can cause, the most obvious one being that people will work separately in different threads without seeing each other's results and will thus needlessly duplicate each other's efforts.

Comment: Are you seriously asking whether $<b_1,b_2,...,b_n>$ = $<c_1,c_2,...,c_n>$ $\Rightarrow$ $<c_1,c_2,...,c_n>$ = $<b_1,b_2,...,b_n>$?

Comment: @Sugata and Marc: I think "$B$ spans the subspace spanned by $C$" is intended to mean that $B$ spans at least that subspace, i.e. "spans ..." in the sense of "can represent ... as linear combinations".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does. If it didn't, there'd be a vector $b$ spanned by $\{b_1,\dotsc,b_n\}$ independent of $\{c_1,\dotsc,c_n\}$, so $\{c_1,\dotsc,c_n,b\}$ would span an $(n+1)$-dimensional space, contradicting the fact that $\{b_1,\dotsc,b_n\}$ spans that space.

Comment: Only if the dimension is finite.

Answer (score 2):

On a more poetic way to express this. I'll take a shot :) Below I'll consider both finite-dimensional and infinite-dimensional vector spaces over an arbitrary field $k$. You can think $k = \mathbb{R}$ if you like, it's not crucial.

Consider a vector space $V$ over the field $k$. There is a function $S \mapsto kS$ that takes each subset $S \subset V$ to its span $kS = \operatorname{span}S$ - the minimal subspace of $V$ containing $S$, that is the set of all elements that can be expressed as *finite* linear combinations of elements of $S$.

Interesting facts about this function:

1. $S \subset kS$ for any $S$,
2. if $T \subset S$, then $kT \subset kS$,
3. $k(kS) = kS$ for any $S$.

These properties mean that this function is a [closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator). I admit I do not know much about closure operators except for *topological* closure operators, so it's just an aside in my answer :)

What's interesting about this function, though, is that it allows us to restate things about linear dependence in a more concise way.

**Definition:** a subset $S \subset V$ is called *linearly dependent* if there exists a proper subset $T \subsetneq S$ such that $kT = kS$. Otherwise we call it *linearly independent*.

**Proposition:** if a subset $S \subset V$ is linearly independent, then all $T \subsetneq S$ are also linearly independent.

*Proof:* Suppose there is $Q \subsetneq T$ such that $kQ = kT$. Then $$k(Q \cup S \setminus T) = k(kQ \cup k(S \setminus T)) = k(kT \cup k(S \setminus T)) = k(kS) = kS,$$ which contradicts the premise.

Consider all linearly independent subsets of $V$ ordered by inclusion.

**Proposition:** There is at least one maximal subset: one that's not included in any other.

*Proof:* Consider a chain $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset \ldots$, where each $S_i$ is linearly independent. Then $S = \bigcup_i S_i$ is also linearly independent: suppose $T \subsetneq S$ has the property $kT = kS$, then $T \cap S_i \subsetneq S_i$ has the property $kS_i = kS \cap kS_i = kT \cap kS_i = k(T \cap kS_i)$, thus by linear independence of $S_i$ we have $T \cap S_i = S_i$ for all $i$. But then $T = \bigcup_i (T \cap S_i) = \bigcup_i S_i = S$, which contradicts the premise. Therefore $S$ is indeed linearly independent. Apply the [Zorn lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn_lemma) to complete the proof.

**Proposition:** if $S \subset V$ is a basis of $V$, then $kS = V$.

*Proof:* Suppose $v \in V \setminus kS$. Then $S \subsetneq S \cup \{v\}$, and $S \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent, which contradicts the maximality of the basis.

**Definition:** we call such a maximal linearly independent subset $S \subset V$ a *basis* of $V$.

**Proposition:** Let $S$ be a basis of $V$, and $U$ be a vector space over $k$. Then for every function $f: S \to U$ there is a unique linear operator $\varphi: V \to U$ such that for each $s \in S$ we have $\varphi(s) = f(s)$.

*Proof:* For any (finite) linear combination $v = a_1 s_1 + \ldots + a_k s_k$ we have $\varphi(v) = a_1 f(s_1) + \ldots a_k f(s_k)$, thus $f$ is uniquely defined on $kS = V$.

UPD: looks like the dimension theorem cannot be easily recast into these terms. Oh well :(

---

It gets even more poetic once we bring in category theory :)

Answer (score 1):

The following are for finite dimensional vector spaces.

If you don't know, prove:

- $\dim(\text{span}(S))\leq |S|$ with equality iff $S$ is linearly independent, where $|S|$ is the cardinality of $S$.
- If $U\leq V$ then $U=V \iff \dim(U)=\dim(V)$.

Denote $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ and $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\}.$
Since $\text{span}(B)\leq\text{span}(C)$ and $\dim(\text{span}(B))=\dim(\text{span}(C)) \Longrightarrow \text{span}(B)=\text{span}(C).$